# Percentage completed status of stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I want to update the WPF progress bar as the progress of stored procedure completed.

In my stored procedure i am doing

```
Insert INTO dbo.tbllist
(

)
select * from dbo.tbllist where condition
```

In my select statement suppose 100 rows then i want to update the UI in percentage (how much percent of row is inserted) .how can i achieve this .Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should assume that the `insert` happens as a single transaction.  That means that you cannot really get a good idea of how many rows are really inserted while the insert is taking place.

If you really want to put this in your GUI, then you need to do two things:

- Count the number of rows that match the condition
- Batch the inserts

You need both to get the percentage being inserted.  This means putting the `insert` into a `while` loop with some sort of pagination ability (and that depends on the database).  For 100 rows, this doesn't seem useful.  For larger inserts, the overhead to manage all this would probably add to the duration of the query.